# JS audio иногда не проигрывается

Tags: javascript, html, аудио, web-audio

На сайте есть расписание, таймер- отсчитывающий время до следующего запланированного, по истечении времени проигрывается звук. Необходимо нажатие на кнопку для прекращения звука.

Но иногда звук не проигрывается, но функция, воспроизводящая звук, точно вызывается- так как также в это время открывается модальное окно.

Существенные моменты кода:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    audio = new Audio('/sound/remind.mp3');

    $("#ops_timer_modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        clearInterval(timer_audio);
        upload();
    });
});

function timer(name){
  if(timer<1000)
    {       
        audio.play();
        if ('timer_audio' in window)
                clearInterval(timer_audio);
        timer_audio = setInterval(function() {
                audio.play();
        }, 3000);

        $('#ops_timer_modal').modal('show');
        $('#modal_timer_span').html("It's time for "+name);                 
    }
  }
```

Функция timer вызывается каждую секунду, она отсчитывает время (эти строки убрал из ненадобности)

Консоль никаких ошибок не выдает.

Идеи?

Comment: Добавляй звук созданием на странице <audio>, а для выключения, удаляй его.

Comment: А если html5 не поддерживается?

Comment: Ну тогда проблема.. Ты попросил идея, я подкинул)